# Conditional distribution of the exponential distribution given Geometric distribution

Tags: exponential-function, conditional-probability

Suppose $X$ is a exponential random variable  with $exp(1)$, 
i.e., the density function $f(x)=f_X(x)=e^{-x}$, 
the cumulative distribution function 
$F(x)=F_X(x)=1-e^{-x}$, where $x>0$.
Let $Y=[X+1]$ (the floor function, i.e., $Z-1<[Z]\leq Z$), 
then find the conditional distribution of 
$X-5$ given $Y\geq 5$.

I tried to solve it as follows:

Let $S(t)=P(X-5>t|Y\geq 5)$. 
By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482594), we 
get $Y$ is  a geometric random variable, with $P(Y=n)=(1-p)^{n-1}p$. 
Then we can compute $P(Y\geq 5)=(1-p)^4$ and 
$S(t)=P(X-5>t|Y\geq 5)=\frac{P(X-5>t, Y\geq 5)}{(1-p)^4}$.
How about next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $Y \geq 5$ iff $X+1 \geq 5$ or $X \geq 4$.

Comment: Tks! @Kavi Rama Murthy Then $S(t)=P(X>5+t,X\geq 4)/(1-p)^4=P(X>5+t)/(1-p)^4$ holds for $t>-1$. Note that $p=1-e^{-1}$, $P(X>5+t)=e^{-(5+t)}$, we have $F(t)=1-S(t)=1-e^{-(t+1)}$, where $t>-1$. Am I right?